# I keep getting these errors while installing Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb, 15.04

I am trying to dualboot Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1 but I am unable to do so because I keep getting some errors.

Steps that I did :-

- Created a LiveUSB Disk of Ubuntu 15.04
- Booted into Ubuntu and Selected Installation by "Something Else"
- Set **Root** to 15GB, **Swap** to 8GB and **Home** to 30GB
- Clicked Install Now and got this error :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpQt9.jpg
- Ignored the error and Clicked Continue
- Ubuntu 15.04 gets Installed but now I cant boot in. Windows 8.1 opens automatically and there is no way to get to GRUB and select Ubuntu.
- Read somewhere that I should try to create another Ubuntu 15.04 LiveUSB and Install something called **BootRepair** to fix the issue. Did that and got this new error :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/abdG2.jpg

Now I somehow managed to install Ubuntu but there is no way of booting into it. What do I do now?

Comment: If Windows is pre-installed then it is in  UEFI boot mode. And if the installer wants a bios_grub partition you are installing in BIOS boot mode. You can add partition with gparted and use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. But you may have to go into UEFI each time you switch and turn  on/off UEFI or BIOS boot modes. UEFI & BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot modes are not compatible and you have to totally reboot to switch modes. Be sure to always boot in UEFI mode. Your flash drive show show two boot options, one clearly UEFI and the other just name of flash drive. Always boot in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a BIOS boot partition since your disk is GPT and you used legacy mode.
 It must be located at the start of a GPT disk, and have a bios_grub flag. It needs 1MB size.