# GRUB only shows Windows 8 loader option, clicking on it brings back the GRUB menu

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-8

I think I've overwritten Windows boot loader with GRUB.

My question is how to configure GRUB so that it starts listing my Windows 8 installation.

**Following is the content of the boot-repair pastebin:**

```
Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 23Nov2014]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (3.00-3.35) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                       and looks at sector 598100496 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. No errors found in the Boot 
                       Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /wubildr /wubildr.mbr

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 15.10 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 16392 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg /casper/vmlinuz.efi 
                       /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *             64   413,545,229   413,545,166   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         413,546,496   434,026,495    20,480,000  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         434,028,542   625,141,759   191,113,218   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         434,028,544   625,141,759   191,113,216  83 Linux


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 4016 MB, 4016046080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 488 cylinders, total 7843840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048     7,843,839     7,841,792   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        C878D5A678D59412                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        05671cad-443c-4931-afc2-bcdab0e7afc2   swap       
/dev/sda5        7622ced3-72a7-41f6-be14-db2b34853749   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        AE6E-4908                              vfat       BOOT-REPAIR
/dev/zram0       bc609267-2d12-46bb-a69f-f1653fc32d4c   swap       
/dev/zram1       e85f535b-c8da-4d75-9248-b428bab247c5   swap       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 11 10:50 ata-Optiarc_DVD_RW_AD-7580S_SL94924340 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 11 10:52 ata-WDC_WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXN0EA9VPP16 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:52 ata-WDC_WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXN0EA9VPP16-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 ata-WDC_WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXN0EA9VPP16-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 ata-WDC_WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXN0EA9VPP16-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 ata-WDC_WD3200BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXN0EA9VPP16-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 11 10:51 usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_WWWF0SVA-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 usb-JetFlash_Transcend_4GB_WWWF0SVA-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Feb 11 10:52 wwn-0x50014ee001d4b9b2 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:52 wwn-0x50014ee001d4b9b2-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 wwn-0x50014ee001d4b9b2-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 wwn-0x50014ee001d4b9b2-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 11 10:50 wwn-0x50014ee001d4b9b2-part5 -> ../../sda5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-C878D5A678D59412' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  C878D5A678D59412
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C878D5A678D59412
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7622ced3-72a7-41f6-be14-db2b34853749 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=05671cad-443c-4931-afc2-bcdab0e7afc2 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Boot-Repair-Disk session" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================== sdb1/syslinux.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda3

00000000  14 91 fa c2 e2 ea ba b7  1c 74 ac 20 f6 35 db b1  |.........t. .5..|
00000010  77 5c 3c 16 97 1d 2f 8b  14 56 8f 24 fa df e4 cf  |w\<.../..V.$....|
00000020  ed f3 5b ef d5 75 98 1a  59 c4 84 97 6d 42 9f b4  |..[..u..Y...mB..|
00000030  a2 51 70 0e 3c 8a 38 9d  42 0d 0a 88 58 bf 01 56  |.Qp.<.8.B...X..V|
00000040  bd b2 14 4b 65 2f b1 2e  2a 32 02 df 7b 46 42 16  |...Ke/..*2..{FB.|
00000050  06 89 77 dd 90 9b 45 dc  a9 43 34 a3 ee c9 7f 71  |..w...E..C4....q|
00000060  c0 00 b6 fd ac 32 30 5a  c8 f9 b1 15 c7 07 32 b0  |.....20Z......2.|
00000070  3c a9 88 9d 21 db 9e 8f  83 29 65 3d 70 08 b8 bd  |<...!....)e=p...|
00000080  59 ee 11 d4 d6 5a 1d 2a  05 36 87 51 07 b3 63 ad  |Y....Z.*.6.Q..c.|
00000090  86 dd 8c ed 94 96 9d ef  36 7a 7a 29 d1 de bf 56  |........6zz)...V|
000000a0  61 46 11 80 2b 4d d8 4b  8c 7f c7 ae b6 ea 45 e1  |aF..+M.K......E.|
000000b0  b7 d2 84 2c 0d ec 98 4d  c6 74 c3 41 9e 80 77 ba  |...,...M.t.A..w.|
000000c0  43 28 1e ec 6a df cf be  95 d8 84 12 c1 46 13 5a  |C(..j........F.Z|
000000d0  4a 63 cf 9e d5 d3 44 1e  fe 83 2e c0 a6 9c 7d 57  |Jc....D.......}W|
000000e0  26 07 0c 60 79 96 42 85  21 52 bd 50 90 8c 2f 04  |&..`y.B.!R.P../.|
000000f0  6c 30 db b1 9b 2b 15 3b  b3 40 69 86 0f 21 4f 34  |l0...+.;.@i..!O4|
00000100  6b d9 c6 53 ef a6 6a 6f  16 4e 2c 35 bb f0 d7 06  |k..S..jo.N,5....|
00000110  d8 e5 0d 89 f1 47 06 0c  66 78 02 6c e2 10 6d 09  |.....G..fx.l..m.|
00000120  7a 6b 62 ab 49 64 85 42  c1 0a 39 ab ad ef fe 80  |zkb.Id.B..9.....|
00000130  13 84 22 6d cc 8a 60 1d  c4 9c 37 d5 5d 4e af 90  |.."m..`...7.]N..|
00000140  10 59 93 bf f8 ae 00 87  3e f8 12 e6 b4 3f a9 36  |.Y......>....?.6|
00000150  2a 54 57 ff f1 61 39 51  62 8a e8 09 c6 2e 98 f8  |*TW..a9Qb.......|
00000160  12 08 a5 a0 83 69 a1 27  22 a1 3c 01 c6 0c e5 13  |.....i.'".<.....|
00000170  c0 25 70 53 1c 44 bb bf  bf 0f 69 cb f3 21 40 1e  |.%pS.D....i..!@.|
00000180  2e 66 ee be 55 c3 d0 75  7e 28 96 c1 ad 44 4b 0e  |.f..U..u~(...DK.|
00000190  78 f1 3a 54 d4 c5 19 e6  dd 90 ac 83 49 dc 5c f1  |x.:T........I.\.|
000001a0  d9 2e 6e ed 33 d5 77 00  3c 87 50 f0 5c a7 11 c4  |..n.3.w.<.P.\...|
000001b0  67 20 59 50 9c cb bd 66  f6 9a cc 52 38 5f 00 fe  |g YP...f...R8_..|
000001c0  ff ff 83 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 28 64 0b 00 00  |...........(d...|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

hexdump: u: bad byte count
/usr/share/boot-sav/bis.sh: line 1746: [: -eq: unary operator expected
cat: write error: Broken pipe
File descriptor 9 (/proc/2006/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 9913: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[27836]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 9913: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2016-02-11__10h50 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa14
boot-sav version : 4ppa14
glade2script version : 3.2.2~ppa47~saucy
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa14
File descriptor 9 (/proc/2006/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 4637: /bin/sh
No volume groups found
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 29nov2014, trusty, Ubuntu, x86_64)
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Windows 8 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda5:Ubuntu 15.10 (15.10):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="C878D5A678D59412" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="05671cad-443c-4931-afc2-bcdab0e7afc2" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda5: UUID="7622ced3-72a7-41f6-be14-db2b34853749" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="BOOT-REPAIR" UUID="AE6E-4908" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/zram0: UUID="bc609267-2d12-46bb-a69f-f1653fc32d4c" TYPE="swap"
/dev/zram1: UUID="e85f535b-c8da-4d75-9248-b428bab247c5" TYPE="swap"


1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== sda5/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Oct 21 16:02 grub.d
total 76
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9791 Oct 14 16:36 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6058 Sep  4 11:13 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12261 Oct 14 16:36 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11082 Oct 14 16:36 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 Aug 27 13:04 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 Oct 14 16:36 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Oct 14 16:36 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Oct 14 16:36 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Oct 14 16:36 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Oct 14 16:36 README




=================== sda5/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"



=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda5    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda5.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 64 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD3200BEVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      32.8kB  212GB  212GB   primary   ntfs            boot
2      212GB   222GB  10.5GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)
3      222GB   320GB  97.8GB  extended
5      222GB   320GB  97.8GB  logical   ext4


Model: JetFlash Transcend 4GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4016MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  4016MB  4015MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba




Error: /dev/zram0: unrecognised disk label



Error: /dev/zram1: unrecognised disk label

=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:320GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA WDC WD3200BEVT-2;
1:32.8kB:212GB:212GB:ntfs::boot;
2:212GB:222GB:10.5GB:linux-swap(v1)::;
3:222GB:320GB:97.8GB:::;
5:222GB:320GB:97.8GB:ext4::;

BYT;
/dev/sdb:4016MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:JetFlash Transcend 4GB;
1:1049kB:4016MB:4015MB:fat32::boot, lba;



Error: /dev/zram0: unrecognised disk label



Error: /dev/zram1: unrecognised disk label


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=lubuntu)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 type ext4 (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  agpgart autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hpet input kmsg log mapper mcelog mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda5 sdb sdb1 sg0 sg1 sg2 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom v4l vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/sda1
00000000  eb 63 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.c.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 40 00 00 00  |........?...@...|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  cd 32 a6 18 00 00 00 00  |.........2......|
00000030  77 87 86 01 00 00 00 00  fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |w...............|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  12 94 d5 78 a6 d5 78 c8  |...........x..x.|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 80 10 4a a6 23  |.....3.......J.#|
00000060  00 00 00 00 ff fa 90 90  f6 c2 80 74 05 f6 c2 70  |...........t...p|
00000070  74 02 b2 80 ea 79 7c 00  00 31 c0 8e d8 8e d0 bc  |t....y|..1......|
00000080  00 20 fb a0 64 7c 3c ff  74 02 88 c2 52 bb 17 04  |. ..d|<.t...R...|
00000090  f6 07 03 74 06 be 88 7d  e8 17 01 be 05 7c b4 41  |...t...}.....|.A|
000000a0  bb aa 55 cd 13 5a 52 72  3d 81 fb 55 aa 75 37 83  |..U..ZRr=..U.u7.|
000000b0  e1 01 74 32 31 c0 89 44  04 40 88 44 ff 89 44 02  |..t21..D.@.D..D.|
000000c0  c7 04 10 00 66 8b 1e 5c  7c 66 89 5c 08 66 8b 1e  |....f..|f..f..|
000000d0  60 7c 66 89 5c 0c c7 44  06 00 70 b4 42 cd 13 72  |`|f...D..p.B..r|
000000e0  05 bb 00 70 eb 76 b4 08  cd 13 73 0d 5a 84 d2 0f  |...p.v....s.Z...|
000000f0  83 d0 00 be 93 7d e9 82  00 66 0f b6 c6 88 64 ff  |.....}...f....d.|
00000100  40 66 89 44 04 0f b6 d1  c1 e2 02 88 e8 88 f4 40  |@f.D...........@|
00000110  89 44 08 0f b6 c2 c0 e8  02 66 89 04 66 a1 60 7c  |.D.......f..f.`||
00000120  66 09 c0 75 4e 66 a1 5c  7c 66 31 d2 66 f7 34 88  |f..uNf.|f1.f.4.|
00000130  d1 31 d2 66 f7 74 04 3b  44 08 7d 37 fe c1 88 c5  |.1.f.t.;D.}7....|
00000140  30 c0 c1 e8 02 08 c1 88  d0 5a 88 c6 bb 00 70 8e  |0........Z....p.|
00000150  c3 31 db b8 01 02 cd 13  72 1e 8c c3 60 1e b9 00  |.1......r...`...|
00000160  01 8e db 31 f6 bf 00 80  8e c6 fc f3 a5 1f 61 ff  |...1..........a.|
00000170  26 5a 7c be 8e 7d eb 03  be 9d 7d e8 34 00 be a2  |&Z|..}....}.4...|
00000180  7d e8 2e 00 cd 18 eb fe  47 52 55 42 20 00 47 65  |}.......GRUB .Ge|
00000190  6f 6d 00 48 61 72 64 20  44 69 73 6b 00 52 65 61  |om.Hard Disk.Rea|
000001a0  64 00 20 45 72 72 6f 72  0d 0a 00 bb 01 00 b4 0e  |d. Error........|
000001b0  cd 10 ac 3c 00 75 f4 c3  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  |...<.u..ressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  967M  5.2M  962M   1% /
udev           devtmpfs   952M   12K  952M   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      194M  1.1M  193M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat       3.8G  614M  3.2G  17% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   549M  549M     0 100% /rofs
none           tmpfs      4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs      967M  8.0K  967M   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      967M     0  967M   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs      100M   16K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      fuseblk    198G   76G  122G  39% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda5      ext4        90G  9.5G   76G  12% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3ffc3ff

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          64   413545229   206772583    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       413546496   434026495    10240000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       434028542   625141759    95556609    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       434028544   625141759    95556608   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 4016 MB, 4016046080 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 488 cylinders, total 7843840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x02a6fa53

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     7843839     3920896    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)




=================== Default settings of Boot Repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s repair-filesystems


=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair


A broken Wubi has been detected. Please fix it this way:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will restore the [(generic mbr)] MBR in sda, and make it boot on sda1.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s repair-filesystems


Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

ntfsfix /dev/sda1
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda1.

fsck -fyM /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
Will restore the MBR_TO_RESTORE : sda (generic mbr) into sda
dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


A broken Wubi has been detected. Please fix it this way:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Cannot_boot_into_Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

**"I think I've overwritten Windows boot loader with GRUB."**

Yes, you did - and unfortunately maybe even way, way more !

There is no Windows operating system installed on the disk.

That is why Windows is not listed and cannot be booted.

When you want to have it back, you have to reinstall it.

Sorry for being the harbinger of the bad news for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have overwritten Windows.
Another thing i noticed is that "SecureBoot maybe enabled." Make sure secureboot is disabled in BIOS completely.
You have to install Windows and make sure you have a recovery media for Windows.
Best of luck.

Comment: No you just installed grub to the PBR - partition boot sector. Testdisk will just call it BS. But you are booting grub with a Windows type boot loader syslinux in MBR. And that loads the boot code in the PBR of sda1, which is grub. You should have grub in MBR of sda, and Windows has more boot code in PBR. NTFS does have backup of PBR and you can use testdisk to restore it. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/655290/grub-is-not-letting-me-switch-to-windows-8-dual-boot-process-ubuntu-15-04/655486#655486