# Can't boot - possibly GRUB issue

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, live-usb

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer but when I try to boot into it the screen just goes black although the computer stays on.

Some information regarding my situation:

- The live-USB worked fine and it said it installed successfully
- I have Windows and Elementary installed on a different disk
- Ubuntu is installed on an external disk (connected over USB) with no other  operating systems
- When I turn on the computer, I select the external drive, GRUB loads and has options for the other operating systems.
- This is the GRUB config file for grub on the disk with Ubuntu ([Log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23309156/))

edit:

- I have tried using boot repair which reinstalls grub but that had no
  effect.
- I have tried all of the advanced options for Ubuntu in the    grub
  menu (to no avail).

Comment: If you get grub menu have you tried recovery mode? Its in advanced options. what video card/chip do you have. If nVidia or AMD you may need nomodeset boot parameter (which recovery mode already has). https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: yes i have tried booting in recovery mode and my graphics card is  an nvidia GeForce 8600 GTS

Comment: Then you do need nomodeset until you install the correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu's repository. Shows both BIOS installer & later the grub menu way to add nomodeset: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 and:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: just to clarify even with nomodeset it does not work

Comment: Use live installer since it boots and run this: May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: These are the details from boot info. http://paste2.org/FE5hdmeC

Answer (score 1):

You do not normally install grub to a partition's boot sector(PBR) and never to a NTFS PBR.

[GRUB is not letting me switch to Windows 8. Dual boot process. Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655290/grub-is-not-letting-me-switch-to-windows-8-dual-boot-process-ubuntu-15-04/655486#655486)

While grub likes to default to install to drive seen as sda, with multiple drives and multiple installs, keep each system's boot loader in the MBR of the drive installed into. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose an install and then choose the drive to install boot loader. Then in BIOS choose to boot system you use the most. But if issues then you can choose from BIOS any other system.

Comment: that still did not I think it may be as the disk is connected over usb 1.0 and is pretty slow plus i managed to install it on another disk through a sata connection.