# Mount NTFS partition after resize

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery, ntfs

I tried to shrink my main NTFS partition from 999GB down to 150GB using ntfsresize and parted.

Now I can't mount my partition again.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/windows
Failed to read last sector (289062495): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

After running a search with TestDisk I get a different start/end compared to parted which is quite curious:

**Testdisk (after search):** start 239616, end 289302112
**Parted:** start 239616s, end 289062515s

So that suggests the problem is the partition MFT has been wiped or there is a problem with the boot sector? [Source](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-partition-boot-sector.htm)

In the Testdisk output before search the error I received:

> Error: size boot_sector 289062497 > partition 288822900

Here Testdisk gives size boot_sector 289062497 > partition 288822900

TestDisk output after search:

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P MS Data                     2048     206847     204800 [ESP]
 P MS Data                   239616  289302112  289062497
 D MS Data               1949329409 1951426560    2097152
 D MS Data               1951426560 1953523711    2097152
```

Testdisk output before search:

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P EFI System                  2048     206847     204800 [EFI system partition]
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 2 P MS Reserved               206848     239615      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 2 P MS Reserved               206848     239615      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
Error: size boot_sector 289062497 > partition 288822900
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 3 P MS Data                   239616  289062515  288822900 [Basic data partition]
 3 P MS Data                   239616  289062515  288822900 [Basic data partition]
 4 P Unknown               1951426560 1953523711    2097152 [Basic data partition]
```

Parted output:

```
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start        End          Size        File system  Name                          Flags
 1      2048s        206847s      204800s     fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      206848s      239615s      32768s                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      239616s      289062515s   288822900s  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      1951426560s  1953523711s  2097152s    ntfs         Basic data partition          diag
```

Comment: NTFS typically needs a chkdsk after a resize and you only can do that from Windows, a Windows repair disk, or installer with a repair console.

Comment: Hi fred thank you for answering, i just tried going into the windows repair command prompt. when i try `chkntfs /f c:` i receive the error `The type of the filesystem is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives`.  I tried `c:` in command prompt and receive the error `This volume does not contain a recognized filesystem`. When i boot ubuntu again the partition info shown in parted is all the same as before

Comment: Raw then means the PBR - partition table boot record or boot sector is empty. It must have essential Windows boot info & partition size data in it. Chkdsk resets the size info. There is a back up if that is only issue. [HowTo] Repair the bootsector of a Windows partition  - YannBuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1926510 & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/655290/grub-is-not-letting-me-switch-to-windows-8-dual-boot-process-ubuntu-15-04/655486#655486

Answer (score 0):

Always solve NTFS problems on Windows itself as it's proprietary software.

Now that `chkntfs` has reported:

> The type of the filesystem is RAW.

please **restore your backup and try again** as something went wrong and you've lost all data on the partition.

### Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I did solve the issue and my problem.

The key was that I knew the start/end sectors where my data was even though I couldnt mount the partition. (from parted output it shows  start: 239616s   end: 289062515s ). So i basically was careful not to overwrite these ares of the disk regardless of whaichever tool i was using.

Eventually i recovered the partition using testdisk. I had to go through the process of Analyze/Quick Search/Write a few times before it found the partition I was looking for (start: 239616s   end: 289062515s). Once it did that I wrote the new boot sector and after restart I could mount it again without any data loss.

Anyone in this situation dont panic! Just remember where you data is on the disc and be careful not to overwrite it.