# windows no longer boots in dual boot after accidentally delete partition in hdd windows

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, external-hdd

I accidentally delete my HDD partition which i used for ubuntu (dual booth) , i recovered using aomei partition which said that the file are restored in the previous partition in disk management

here the data is recovered in 71.88 RAW

[image]

but i cant access the GNU grub when i try to start the computer, which I usually can choose to open windows or ubuntu by pressing F6 .
my question are:

do i have to reinstall ubuntu again?

do i have to make live USB ubuntu again?

do i only need to repair the grub ?

do I have to try to install Ubuntu and be able to dual boot alongside windows?

Comment: Looks like older BIOS/MBR version. Windows BIOS/MBR often "forgets" Linux partitions when it updates partition table. RAW means a NTFS partition is not formatted or it lost format. Often you can restore PBR from a backup & then run chkdsk. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition & https://askubuntu.com/questions/655290/grub-is-not-letting-me-switch-to-windows-8-dual-boot-process-ubuntu-15-04/655486#655486

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. in Windows, download Ubuntu image (e.g., [Bionic Beaver 18.04.5](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.5/ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso));
2. burn it to a blank USB, I would use [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.13/rufus-3.13.exe) for that;
3. check that all your hard drives are connected as they should be;
4. boot from the Ubuntu USB (for that, change BIOS options or press keys at boot as necessary);
5. check that you have Internet access in Ubuntu;
6. install [Boot-Repair, 2nd option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

7. run Recommended Repair when prompted;
8. read messages carefully and press Enter to confirm your choices;
9. get to the end, note the URL (**paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX**) just in case;
10. reboot, it should resolve you problems;
11. if not, please post the URL in the comments;
12. for the future, try to have Ubuntu live boot USB by your side.

Good luck!